# Deleting WordPress posts and media file based on author in MYSQL database

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress

I would like to delete some of the posts on a wordpress website between a time period based on an author via the MYSQL database. I couldn't identify which tables I should join to delete these posts. The below query is just for your understanding(the actual query might involve some joins). Appreciate your help.

```
Delete from wp-posts where post-author = 'name' AND published-date BETWEEN 01/01/2024 AND 20/03/2024;
```

Comment: You need to _delimit_ the object names if they contain dashes. MySQL uses back-ticks for this.

Comment: What difficulty are you having in identifying the relationships? The WP tables are pretty straightforward.

Comment: `01/01/2024` is arithmetic, not a date; furthermore dates must be with year first to compare correctly: `"2024/01/01"`.

Comment: @Rick James DELETE wp_posts FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID 
WHERE post_author = 1 AND post_date BETWEEN '2024-03-28 00:00:00' AND '2024-03-28 23:59:59'; this is what i wanted to achieve, thank you

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way directly related to PHP or Wordpress? "I have some difficulties identifying the WordPress tables" -  what exactly does that even mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase This was related to the WordPress database and its tables. I was supposed to join wp_users and wp posts tables to delete the posts posted between a period based on an author, unfortunately, I had difficulties identifying which table's column I was supposed to join before

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: Are those values in `wp-posts` or in the attribute table?